# Excel: cross-book, reference all worksheets implicitly

Tags: excel

I am trying to reference all of the worksheets in another workbook implicitly without using direct references. The code I am working with is to be used to reference books of varying size, so defining a range rigidly is not optimal here.

I suppose you could say im looking for something like

'[Book.xlsx]ALL'!A1
or
'[Book.xlsx]*'!A1

Tl:dr i want a formula to look at every cell in a given range in a book without having to rigidly define every sheet it needs to look at in the formula. Context is VLOOKUP.

Comment: What if the workbook has 4 sheets? How do you know which sheet to reference? Or, are you positive each book only has one sheet? If so, `Sheets(1)` would be the appropriate reference

Comment: The books sheet count varies. Some can have just one. Some can have 10. Some could potentially have as many as 20.

Comment: Well, if the book has 20, which sheet do you want?

Comment: I want to look at all of them. Theoretically, the value i need should only be on one sheet. However, I need multiple values across multiple sheets, and the amount of sheets is not static and i want to eliminate as much user input as possible.

Comment: You want a sheet loop then

Comment: I am not well versed in excel syntaxand am only barely getting by on my programming experience in R:Base. If you could help me create this "sheet loop" i would be grateful

Comment: Still not enough info here. Do you want to store all the value of each  VLOOKUP or only the ones that don’t generate an error? Or just the first one that doesn’t get an answer? Where do you want the result[s] stored? Sheet loops are well documented on this site. You may need to revise your question with more details

Comment: I work for a survey company and we do things called level runs for various purposes. In this case, its for monitoring wells where we need the ground elevation and the casing elevation. I have the algorithm to get those values right now, but it requires direction. I am currently required to tell it what sheet to look at to get those values. I want to remove that requirement, forcing it to just look at every sheet within the workbook, since the amount of sheets varies based on how many level runs are done. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If it helps at all, this is my current formula, with some stuff changed of course: =VLOOKUP($B6&"|Ground",CHOOSE({1,2},'[Book.xlsx]Sheet'!$B:$B&"|"&'[Book.xlsx]Sheet'!$J:$J,'[Book.xlsx]Sheet'!$H:$H),2,0) --- this gives me what I want. The only problem is that I want to change "Sheet" to whatever I need to to get it to look at the entire book instead of one specific sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this can do the job :

```
Sub loopOverWoorkbookWorksheet()

Dim directory As String
Dim StrFile, wbs() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

' Getting all the xlsx file from your directory
directory = "your_directory"
i = 0
StrFile = Dir(directory & "\*.xlsx")

Do While Len(StrFile)

   ReDim Preserve wbs(i)
   wbs(i) = StrFile
   StrFile = Dir
   i = i + 1

Loop

' Loop through all the sheet of one workbook
For Each wb In wbs

   workbooks.Open Filename:=directory & "\" & wb

   For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
   ' Do your compute
   ' You can store the result in a Cell using :
   ' Cells(x,y) = z
   ' x : number of the line
   ' y : number of the column
   ' z : the data you want to store in the cell
   Next ws

Next wb

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I dont know if this was the correct course, but my boss has opted for a different (and in my opinion less elegant ) route.

Comment: I don't know either maybe it is more maintainable the way your boss did it but in my opion, I think it's quite flexible, especially if you want to loop through  previous version of Excel file like `.xls`